# PortSIP: change video resolution during a call

Tags: video, voip

I am using PortSip VoIP DSK for video calling in a soft.
I'm trying to change the resolution during a call but the receiver of the video didn't receive the modification.

I use PortSIPCore.setVideoResolution().
- If I change then start a call, the method PortSIPCore.onVideoRawCallback() receives the width and heigth of the remote video.
- If I start the call with a low resolution, then change to high resolution during the call, something happen as video seems pixelate in a different manner (less blurred) but it's never the good looking of starting with the high resolution. onVideoRawCallback() is not called on modification of the resolution.

Perhaps setVideoResolution() ask the video device (webcam) a different resolution but continue sending it to starting dimensions.

I tried stop and restart the video sending with startVideoSending() or update conversation with updateInvite() but nothing works.

If someone knows how it works and can help, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In sip protocol video(including resolution) is not in protocol, but have be managed by clients(UA)

So you need ensure other side of call support video change(reinvite) in video call and/or do needed changes in both UA, both side.

Comment: I'm using PortSIP VoIP library (version 8.1). It manages the UA parameters between the clients, I can't access them. The email support responds me after I posted this question that it may be a bug they will looked at. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @artheops, is it possible to transfer an audio call to a video call during the conversation?

Comment: That is endpoint-specific. SIP protocol have Re-INVITE, which CAN be used, but that depend of IMPLEMENTATION

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in PortSIP VoIP SDK.

There is impossible to change the video resolution during the call if using the H.263/h.263+ codec. You have to set the resolution before you make the call!.

Best regards,